# Getting "__r" relationship name from Schema.SObjectType.Fields

Tags: dynamic-soql, describesobject, namespace, schema, sobjecttype

Say I have a master-detail relationship between two objects, `Schematic__c` and `Part__c`.

I can SOQL query the master from the detail: `[SELECT Schematic__r.Name FROM Part__c]`

If I'm building a query from strings, I resolve the schema name, for example in a managed package:

```
SObjectType.Part__c.Fields.Schematic__c.Name //gives me 'ns__Schematic__c'
```

But when traversing into the master object, the **`__r` relationship suffix** is what I need to surface. I've toyed around with the obvious Schema.SObjectType variations but I'm not having much luck:

```
SObjectType.Part__c.Fields.Schematic__r.Name //Schematic__r is not a field of ns__Symbol__c
```

What's the correct way to resolve the `ns__Schematic__r.Name` token without replacing the suffix?

Comment: I can see a feature within the _Field Sets_ offering that gets me close: 1. go to the `Part__c` object and create a new _Field Set_, 2. drag `Part Name` and `Schematic Name` into the Field Set, 3. exec `SObjectType.Part__c.FieldSets.MyFieldSetName.fields[1].FieldPath` which gives `ns__Schematic__r.Name`, but Field Sets are subject to removal and rearrangement etc.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No no, the field (API) name is `Schematic__c`, you need to start from it. Think about `Schematic__r` (the rel. name) like a consistent table alias when you'd make JOINs in regular database, nothing more.

**To go "up":**

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.Order_Line_Item__c.fields.Order__c;
System.debug(f.getRelationshipName()); 
// Outputs "Order__r", also with namespace if you have one
```

(You could also play with checking `f.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.REFERENCE` if you need to describe all fields and wonder which ones are lookups)

**to go "down":**

```
for(Schema.ChildRelationship cr : Order__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships()){
    System.debug(cr.getChildSObject() + '.' + cr.getField() + ' reversed is: ' + cr.getRelationshipName());
}

ActivityHistory.WhatId reversed is: ActivityHistories
Attachment.ParentId reversed is: Attachments
ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId reversed is: null
ContentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId reversed is: null
(...)
Order_Line_item__c.Order__c reversed is: Order_Line_items__r    // bingo
Order__History.ParentId reversed is: Histories
(...)
Task.WhatId reversed is: Tasks
```

Comment: Now we're cooking with gas! And I can evaluate these in Visualforce too: `$ObjectType.Part__c.Fields.Schematic__c.RelationshipName`