# Display History tracking section in visualforce standardcontroller

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, relationships

I am using standard controller of a custom object called Enagements__c to display details of the record in VF Page. I want to use the standard feature of '`<apex:relatedlist`' and display all the related list for that object.

I am not able to display the history tracking section and giving a strange error, even though i give the child relationship name correctly it still gives me a error.

```
<apex:relatedList list="Engagements__history"/>
```

Error i get when see the output is :

```
'Engagements__history' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Engagements
```

I am confused since when query the history tracking from SOQL it works fine which shows that relationship name is correct

> SELECT Id, customfield__c, (SELECT OldValue, NewValue FROM
>   Enagements__history)  FROM Engagements__c

How do we get the history tracking relatedlist of a customobject to use

```
<apex:relatedList list="Engagements__history"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure that SOQL query works? I would expect the relationship name to be `Engagements__Histories`.

Comment: use describe call and check correct relationship name `Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.Order_Line_Item__c.fields.Order__c;
System.debug(f.getRelationshipName());` check this post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23498/getting-r-relationship-name-from-schema-sobjecttype-fields

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box. [Here you can find a custom component created by John De Santiago](http://www.iterativelogic.com/create-your-own-history-related-list-in-visualforce/) - one of the most advanced "native looking" History list recreations.

Comment: recommended; has one issue in that it is hard to test without `seeAllData=true` as you can't mock history records

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue when I tried using History relatedList with a standard controller. I ended up implementing as follows.Let me know if this helps.

```
..
..
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myCustomObject__c.Histories}" var="hist">
<apex:column headerValue="Date" value="{!hist.createddate}"/>
<apex:column headerValue="User" value="{!hist.createdbyid}"/> 
..
..
```